# Install of Windows 10 loops when installing from USB Drive

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive

I have a system running Ubuntu.   I am trying to get rid of Ubuntu and put Windows 10 on the system.  I have a USB created with a 64-bit version of the Media Creation Tool.

At a certain stage in the installation the system will reboot and start the setup process all over again, which I don't understand why it is happening. The only thing that I'm not doing is entering a product key; at that stage I have skipped it since I will be purchasing a key once I can verify the OS works.

This is absolutely frustrating and I'm not too sure how to proceed.

Comment: Can you confirm if your system has the capability to run a 64-bit operating system?

Comment: This happened to me as well, simply unplug the USB device and reboot as normal. WIndows 10 should continue the installation process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your computer's BIOS settings are configured to boot from a USB drive before booting from a hard drive.  When the Windows 10 install reboots, it probably needs to boot up from the hard drive to continue with the install.  Try removing the USB drive completely when the computer restarts - then it will be forced to boot from the hard drive.

You could also edit your BIOS settings so that the USB drive has a lower priority than the hard drive, but then you might have trouble booting into the USB drive the first time.

Comment: Yep, this was what caused the issue for me. I've already finished an install of Windows 10 since then but thanks for the answer!

Comment: Here's what's going on. For some *inconceivable* reason, the installer created using the media creation tool does not have the traditional "press any key to boot off disk" option. Its also not smart enough to realise that there's an install ongoing. So it loops da loop. Amusingly enough after the first reboot, everything is already on the drive, and this would be solved by that, or suggesting you unplug the disk, ala a linux live installer. Bit of a UI fail there.